# jQuery flying notifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have long page. I want show some info, so when user scroll page, this info will follow by the user.

Is any plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Jquery-Floating-Box-Plugin/
http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/floating-message-jquery/
http://amirharel.com/labs/fo/float_demo.html
https://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/018_Floating_Menu/demo/dhtml_float_menu_final_nettut.html
```